# Cleaning code of a class

Tags: java, coding-style

I have a class with 2 instance variables and long method (exact implementation is not important). To make the code look clean I extract methods and give them good names; of course, keep these new methods small.

At the end I have pretty good class with short methods named according to what they do.

The question is about those new private methods who are not using instance variables any more. Is there any good practice what to do with them? should they be static? etc

Please, share you ideas and approaches

Comment: Yes. you can make them static

Comment: @Adi there's no real benefit in having `static private` methods.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah, my bad. removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start wondering if these methods should be in your class to begin with, this is, are you sure this is the responsibility of the class you're working with? If they can be reused in other classes, then move them into an utility class as `public static`.

More info:

- [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: thank.Let's assume these methods are introduced only for code readability - e.g. elmination of long methods

Comment: @AlanHarper assume **nothing**. After you have reduced the methods, the next step is to wonder: do these methods really should be in my class, is not another class that could make a good use of them? If these methods have solely and exclusive usage in your specific class, then leave them as `private`, otherwise move them into an utility class to make them reusable (even for a small set of classes).